# How to redirect after login in drupal 9 without any module?

Tags: authentication, redirect, drupal-9

we have to upgrade drupal 8.9 to drupal 9.3.3 and since then the login_destination module stop working and we don't know why. i've tried others modules like Anonymous Login, Redirect After Login, User Redirect but no of them seem to work.

In some sites they commented that this redirect can be solved without module but i dont know how.

Basically what im trying to do is that when we set the "destination" parameter in URL, drupal redirects you to the destination path after the login.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195170/redirect-after-user-login This might answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the url by adding the destination-parameter to your login-url:

```
https://example.com/user/login?destination=/path/to/go
```

And maybe you can add something like this in your htaccess-file (not tested):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^user/login$ /user/login?destination=path/to/go [L]
```